# Get "start_date" from Excel function NETWORKDAYS

Tags: excel

`NETWORKDAYS (start_date, end_date, [holidays])`

If we already known the value of NETWORKDAYS, end_date and [holidays],
is it possible to get the *start_date* instead?

Example:

```
NETWORKDAYS: 5 
end_date: 1/1
Holidays: 12,30,12/31
```

Is it possible to get the *"start_date"* automatically?

Comment: Yes. Use the `WORKDAY` function.

Comment: @LifeOfJona,
thank you for the help! 
I didn't express myself clear enough...

I am not trying to get "date" without month.
I want to have the "start_date" as my result.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld
Why I don't Use "Workdays",
because I want to count the date backwards.

I know the deadline (end_date)
but Function Workdays can only calculate it forward (using start_date as base to add workdays).

But anyway, thank you for giving me the comment!

Comment: As far as I know you need to use VBA to do this. See my answer below.

Comment: Not true. `WORKDAY` can calculate forward or backward. Did you try it?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld 
omg...  Orzzzzz
i added "minus" before the workdays.... and it works
thank you!

Comment: I posted it as an answer to demonstrate after you commented about counting backwards. If it is what you want, you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the WORKDAY function.

Because `NETWORKDAYS` includes both the start and end dates, and `WORKDAY` is an addition, you need to add `1` to the negative networkdays value

eg:  `=WORKDAY(B9,-B8+1,B10:C10)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is something like this:

[image]

This is made using a UDF (VBA code in a formula).
Open the VBA editor (ALT + F11)
Add a new module
Paste the following code:

```
Function countdays(EndDate As Date, Days As Integer)
    
    i = 1
    While Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(EndDate - i, EndDate) < Days
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    
    countdays = EndDate - i
End Function
```

Save the workbook as a mackroenabled workbook. XLSM or XLSB

This will loop backwards start date until it NetworkDays return the correct number of days, then return that date in the cell.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is exactly what I want!
But there is one more thing I'm still stuck at...
I want to keep the [Holidays] from the old function,
however, I am new to VBA can't really make it work properly...